# Libjpeg not found by my program even though it exists

Tags: shared-library, dynamic-linking

I have a binary program to run on Ubuntu 12.04. It has shared object dependency. pmvs is the name of the program

```
   $ ldd pmvs
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff043c3000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fa14dc9a000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fa14d964000)
        libjpeg.so.62 => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa14d747000)
        liblapack.so.3 => not found
        libgsl.so.0 => not found
        libgslcblas.so.0 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa14d449000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa14d149000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa14cf33000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa14cb73000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fa14c955000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa14c751000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa14dece000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fa14c54d000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fa14c347000)
```

It apparently cannot find libjpeg.so. However I am sure that it exists and is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so`. How do I set the linker path to include that location?

Answer (score 2):

Since other libraries are successfully being found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, your problem is not how to specify that location, but probably the version number of the installed library is not 62 like the program is looking for.

You have two choices, either find and install an old version of the missing library, or much easier and likely to succeed is to just add the missing library as a link to the version of the library installed.

Now Ubuntu 14.04 has `libjpeg.so.8.0.2`, so something is drastically different.  However, I do have a
`/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libjpeg.so.62/libjpeg.so.62` on my 14.04 system, so maybe you have something similar (I have vmplayer installed).  If the `libjpeg.8.0.2` library does not work for the link, look around for something vmware install left around (the player is a free download if you need it).

Answer (score 2):

Installing an older version of libjpeg solved my problem

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case that apt-get didn't work , I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg.git
```

and then:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```